# Can't get complete response using @JsonProperty from Array

Tags: java, arrays, json, resttemplate

Problem that I faced today is like this - What I'm trying to do is to get a list of types of Pokemons from [Pokemon API](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/). And the response is shown as below:

```
{
  "count": 20,
  "results": [
     {"name": "normal", "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/1/"},
     {"name": "fighting", "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/2/"}
  ]
}
```

What I have actually get is only the first (test) part that means `count`. I left it only to be sure I have any response. But the problem is with `results` because I'm getting only nulls. And I don't know how to handle it.

My Classes responsible for application are like that:

```
public class PokemonClient {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public MainResponse response() {

        URI url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type").build().encode().toUri();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.add("User-Agent", "cheese");
        HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<MainResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, MainResponse.class);

        Optional<MainResponse> search = Optional.ofNullable(response.getBody());
        return search.orElseGet(MainResponse::new);
    }
}

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MainResponse {
    @JsonProperty("count")
    private Integer count;

    @JsonProperty("typeList")
    private GetType[] typeList;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MainResponse{" +
                "count=" + count +
                ", typeList=" + typeList +
                '}';
    }
}

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GetType {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

}
```

I'm sure it should be something with handling the array with results but after day of trying I'm out of ideas how to deal with it. Please for any helpful pointers :)

Comment: Try to modify `@JsonProperty("typeList")` to `@JsonProperty("results")`.

Comment: Thanks alot. It worked :)